# when you retrieve a javascript object from local storage, does it load the entire object into memory?

Tags: javascript, object, storage, local

when you retrieve a javascript object from local storage, does it load the entire object into memory?

Comment: This site isn't really ideal for yes/no answers without any detail or context.

Comment: I believe that `localStorage` (specifically speaking) is retrieved as `string` rather than `object`.

Answer (score 0):

All Javascript data is stored in memory.  So, yes reading something from LocalStorage will load it into memory.

LocalStorage stores strings so reading something from LocalStorage will be a string in Javascript memory unless/until you parse it into something else.